# Tab inserted after each image in the next line in Latex

Tags: graphics, floats

sorry for my bad english, I'm from Germany ;)

My question:
I inserted Images in Latex like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=300px]{pics/vpn_surface.png}
\centering
\caption{OpenVPN Verbindungsmaske}
\end{figure}
```

Everytime I inserted an image like this, I got a tab in the following
line (under the Image). Like this:

bla bla bla text

--Image-- (fixed Point)

(tab space) bla bla bla following text

How can I remove the tab? I can't find a way to do this. Please help :)

[Tab under image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSQ32.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

to your preamble (just before `\begin{document}`). Or, if you want to remove the *tab space* only after some image, you can locally modify your code

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=300px]{pics/vpn_surface.png}
\centering
\caption{OpenVPN Verbindungsmaske}
\end{figure}

Blah blah...
```

this way:

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=300px]{pics/vpn_surface.png}
\centering
\caption{OpenVPN Verbindungsmaske}
\end{figure}
Blah blah...
```

(this is, removing the blank line), instead of

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=300px]{pics/vpn_surface.png}
\centering
\caption{OpenVPN Verbindungsmaske}
\end{figure}

\noindent Blah blah...
```

according to the two comments below by David Carlisle.

Comment: You should not insert a blank line denoting a new paragraph, and then use `\noindent` to hide that, if it is not a new paragraph _don't use a blank line_

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle what is the easiest approach to advise here? To omit \noindent and comment the blank line? I'll edit my answer consequently, thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't add a blank line at all then there would be no need to comment it out:-) A blank line is not just laying out the source, it is an _instruction_ to end a paragraph and start a new one, so just add them where you want the paragraph to end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know how to edit without altering the answer or making your comments looking obsolete or obscure. Feel free to edit further, thank you for improvements!